# ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] No metadata for "UsersRepository" was found

Tags: typescript, database, express, backend, nest

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'topSecret51',
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: 3600,
      },
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UsersRepository]),
  ],
  providers: [UsersRepository, AuthService, JwtStrategy],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [PassportModule, AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

this is my auth.repository.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersRepository {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private userRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  async findOne(username: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    return this.userRepository.findOne({ where: { username } });
  }

  async createUser(authCredentialsDto: AuthCredentialsDto): Promise<void> {
    const { username, password } = authCredentialsDto;
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    const user = this.userRepository.create({
      username,
      password: hashedPassword,
    });

    try {
      await this.userRepository.save(user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.code);
      if (error.code === '23505') {
        throw new ConflictException('Username already exists');
      } else {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to create offer specifically for a user , with a jwt token through postman i get error in node

```
[Nest] 26564  - 05.07.2023, 11:07:57   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] No metadata for "UsersRepository" was found.
```

However when I try to run the code with just   TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]), or just   TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UsersRepository]), the server does not even start.
I can create a user with sign up, and sign in - receiving the token , but I cannot make user create offers.

Where should I look for answer :) ?